# What does the space in front of a few file names mean on doing git status -s?

Tags: git, git-status

When I do `git status -s` I get the following output:

```
 M package.json
D  public/ewew.js
 M script.sh
M  src/TaskList.js
 D test.js
AD test2.js
```

What does the space in the beginning of few lines mean? (1st, 3rd and 5th line)

Answer (score 5):

`git status -s` shows a two-letter status code in front of the file name, and you can find the explanation in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format):

```
X          Y     Meaning
-------------------------------------------------
          [MD]   not updated
M        [ MD]   updated in index
A        [ MD]   added to index
D         [ M]   deleted from index
R        [ MD]   renamed in index
C        [ MD]   copied in index
[MARC]           index and work tree matches
[ MARC]     M    work tree changed since index
[ MARC]     D    deleted in work tree
-------------------------------------------------
D           D    unmerged, both deleted
A           U    unmerged, added by us
U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
U           A    unmerged, added by them
D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
A           A    unmerged, both added
U           U    unmerged, both modified
-------------------------------------------------
?           ?    untracked
!           !    ignored
-------------------------------------------------
```

In your case, the X is space so this one applies:

```
X          Y     Meaning
-------------------------------------------------
          [MD]   not updated
```

Answer (score 4):

Along with the other things it does, `git status` runs *two* (not one, but **two**) `git diff` commands.  Therefore, when showing you a `--short` or `-s` status output, it needs to summarize the results of *both* diffs—which is why there are *two* positions for each possible status letter.

Remember that Git has, at all times, up to *three* copies of each file.<sup>1</sup>  There's one instance of, e.g., `package.json` in the `HEAD` commit, a second version of `package.json` in the *index* (also called the *staging area* or the *cache*), and a third version of `package.json` in the *work-tree*.

The version of `package.json` in the current commit can never be changed, because no file in any commit can ever be changed.  (You can change *which commit is current*, which will change the `HEAD` version of the file by changing `HEAD` itself: e.g., instead of HEAD being `ac0ffee`, maybe now HEAD is `feeddad`.  But the files stored in those commits are always stored in those commits, forever.)

The version of `package.json` that is stored in the index, though, you can change at any time.  You can't *see* it very well because it's stored in an internal, Git-only form, but you can get it out of the index and look at it, or put something different into the index, whenever you like.

The version of `package.json` that is stored in your work-tree, you can change at any time.  You can see it and change it easily, because it's stored in the ordinary format that your computer uses for any file.

Diagrammatically:

```
  HEAD          index         work-tree
--------       --------       --------
package.json   package.json   package.json
public/ewew.js
script.sh      script.sh      script.sh
           :              :
               test2.js
```

The `git status` command first compares the `HEAD` version to the index version, then compares the index version to the work-tree version.

The status for this `test2.js`, for instance, is `AD`: this means it's *missing* in `HEAD`, so for `HEAD`-vs-index, it has been *added*, and then it is missing *again* in the work-tree, so for index-vs-work-tree, it has been *deleted*.

The status for `script.sh` is space-M, so the versions in `HEAD` and the index match (space) but the versions in the index and the work-tree differ (`M`).  The status for `src/TaskList.js` is M-space, so the version in `HEAD` is different from the version in the index, and the version in the index is the same as the version in the work-tree.

If you were to make a commit right now, what would go into the *new* commit is *whatever is in the index right now*.  To see *everything* that is in the index right now, use `git ls-files --stage`.  Usually, though, the difference between `HEAD` and the index—i.e., the files "staged for commit" or the first column of a short status—is more interesting.  Likewise, the difference between the index and the work-tree—i.e., files you *could* stage for commit—is interesting, so that's why there is a second column.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, Git has, at any time, *up to five* copies of any one file, though sometimes as few as just one.  This is because the index/staging-area is also used when doing a conflicted-file merge resolution—i.e., when you are in the middle of a conflicted merge.  In this case, it holds three copies of one file: the merge-base version, the `--ours` version, and the `--theirs` version.  But for this particular answer, just think of it as "three copies": don't worry about the other cases until you are doing a merge.